# Question about Delegates

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

This code is pretty simple, is it correct?  I don't know if I should be retaining the delegate passed in via the init method.

```
@interface SomeClass : NSObject {
    SomeClassDelegate *someClassDelegate;
}
-(id)initWithDelegate:(SomeClassDelegate *)delegate;
@end

@implementation SomeClass
-(id)initWithDelegate:(SomeClassDelegate *)delegate
{
    [delegate retain]; // should I be doing this?
    someClassDelegate = delegate;
}
-(void)dealloc
{
    [delegate release]; // obviously only do  this if I DO need to retain it
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

My initial thought is no, however this bit of code seems to hint otherwise.  I know I can't rely on retain counts, but I'd like to know the proper way to deal with delegates.

```
// self's retain count is 1
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:self];
// the retain count is now 2, did the init of URLConnection retain self?
```

Comment: NSURLConnection is a bit of a special case. It's not so much that it retains the delegate, but that it retains it _for the duration of the connection_ since the only way to stop receivoing delegate messages is to cancel the connection. i.e. Normally one does not retain a delegate, and NSURLConnection's behaviour like this is an implementation detail; not something you should rely on or generally imitate.

Also, It's unusual to have a delegate _class_. Normally you declare a delegate protocol.

Comment: Thanks Mike, that explains what I'm seeing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, in general, you are not supposed to retain the delegate. Since the delegate already has a reference to your object, if you retained the delegate, you would create a circular reference, essentially. Also, for that same reason, you can assume that your object will be destroyed before the delegate is destroyed.

Check out [these](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html) [articles](http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000075.php) for more information about using/implementing delegates.

EDIT: There are a few exceptions, which have been pointed out by others.

Comment: Thanks for the articles, you confirmed my belief on delegates. Mike also explained to me why I see what I see with NSURLConnection in the comments of my question.

Comment: Depending on the situation, your object may not be destroyed first, but it will at least have the delegate unset. (example: UIAccelerometer)

Answer (score 1):

As htw says, you should not generally retain the delegate. In a multi-threaded environment, you often have to retain everything you need, even if for just a method call's duration, to make sure it doesn't get invalidated behind your back, however. If, for example (not actually the case),  the `-[NSURLConnection initWithRequest:delegate]` created a new thread that thread may have retained (then likely will autorelease) its parameters. In reality, `NSURLConnection` is a special case in that it retains its delegate for the duration of the connection.